# Is there a more functional way to merge and foreach/sort two arrays in TypeScript, React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, foreach, functional-programming

I'm learning React and TypeScript. For sake of practise, I've tried to create a calculator design by merging two arrays to map a single array onto the grid (`display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);`).

**Now I'm wondering if there's a way to do this more effectively with better readability, preferably with functional programming standards?**

```
const numbers = [3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7]
const signs = ["AC", "√", "%", "÷", "*", "-", "+", "00", "0", ".", "="]

const alphanumeric = numbers.toString().split(",").concat(signs)

const fillButtons = () => {  
    const sortedArray: Array<string> = []
    let findSignIndex = 0
    let findNumberIndex = numbers.length - 1

    alphanumeric.forEach((_: string, index: number) => {
        if (index <= 3) {
            sortedArray.push(signs[findSignIndex++])
        }
        else if (index % 3 === 0 && findNumberIndex >= 0) {
            sortedArray.push(numbers[findNumberIndex--].toString())
            sortedArray.push(signs[findSignIndex++])
        }
        else if (findNumberIndex >= 0) {
            sortedArray.push(numbers[findNumberIndex--].toString())
        }
        else if (findSignIndex >= 0 && index < (alphanumeric.length - 3)) {
            sortedArray.push(signs[findSignIndex++])
        }
    });

    return sortedArray
}
```

This is the resulting array:
`['AC', '√', '%', '÷', '7', '8', '9', '*', '4', '5', '6', '-', '1', '2', '3', '+', '00', '0', '.', '=']`

This is the map:

```
{fillButtons().map((character: string, index: number) => (
    <button key={index} className="calculator__button">
        {character}
    </button>
))}
```

This is the result:

[image: This is the result:]

Comment: I don't quite understand the algorithm you're using here, or why you don't just start off with an array that's sorted the way you want to begin with?  It looks like you start with the values in some order generated by a person doing a strange walk through the keys, and then go though a lot of effort to undo that.  Why don't you just start with `['AC', '√', '%', '÷', '7', '8', '9', '*', '4', '5', '6', '-', '1', '2', '3', '+', '00', '0', '.', '=']`?  I was about to say you could filter that if you wanted just the numbers, but then I don't understand why `0` is a "sign" and not a number. Halp!

Comment: pocket calculators are a great way to learn how to implement your first programming language. see some [recent Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+pocket+calculator) i wrote for more help. let me know if you have follow up questions.

Answer (score 0):

## The problem

We want to assign "sign"s to corresponding "slots", but we need to find a declarative way to do it.

Actually there can not be a sensible "functional programming" solution, because the problem is not in the complexity of computation logic, but in the way that we want to store placement of buttons.

## Solution 1

Use declarative power of [grid template areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) and forget about reordering arrays completely.

```css
.controls {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "AC sqrt percent div"
    "n7 n8 n9 mul"
    "n4 n5 n6 sub"
    "n1 n2 n3 sum"
    "doublezero n0 dot eq";
}
```

```
const numbers = [3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7];
const signs = ["AC", "√", "%", "÷", "*", "-", "+", "00", "0", ".", "="];

// but we are forced to store this clunky map, because
// √ % ÷ * + . = can not be used inside a grid area name
const signsToGridLabels = {
  "AC": 'AC',
  "√": 'sqrt',
  "%": 'percent',
  "÷": 'div',
  "*": 'mul',
  "-": 'sub',
  "+": 'sum',
  ".": 'dot',
  "=": 'eq',
  "00": 'doublezero',
};

const App = () => (
    <>
      <div className="display"></div>
      <div className="controls">
        {numbers.concat(signs).map((el) => {
          return (<div style={{ gridArea: signsToGridLabels[el] ?? `n${el}` }}>{el}</div>)
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/temoncher/pen/GRQJKKJ)

## (Not so much of a) Solution 2

Define a single "template" with `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);`

```
const template = [
  'AC', '√', '%', '÷',
  '7', '8', '9', '*',
  '4', '5', '6', '-',
  '1', '2', '3', '+',
  '00', '0', '.', '='
];
```